# Is the conjugate axis of a hyberbola itself a trivial hyperbola?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

The definition of a hyperbola is

> A hyperbola is the set of all points in a plane, the difference of whose distances from two fixed points in the plane is a constant.

By this definition, the perpendicular line passing through the centre of the hyperbola, that is its conjugate axis should be called a hyperbola (may be a trivial hyperbola). As conjugate axis is set of all points such that the difference of their distance from from two foci is always $0$, which is always same, or remains constant. Is this a correct interpretation or am I missing something?

Comment: Any line can be considered a "trivial" hyperbola —the common term is ["degenerate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic)— just as any point is a degenerate circle of radius $0$, and any segment is a degenerate ellipse with minor axis $0$, etc. The conjugate of a hyperbola conveniently shares foci with the given hyperbola, but that's not really such a big deal; any symmetrically-arranged pair of points on the transverse axis can serve as foci.

Comment: @Blue That's interesting. Do you also mean that conjugate is actually defined once we have a hyperbola, and it is just that it conveniently shares the property of being a set of point at a constant difference of distance from foci. But, the same conjugate can be from that perspective a hyperbola for any set of symmetric foci's, which are infinite pairs, whereas hyperbola for a given specific foci is a unique set of curves. Can you help me to know, why the term 'degenerate' is used in this context?

Comment: Questions about *when* an object is defined are a bit too metaphysical for this comment section. (Did a circle of radius $5$ with center $(12,34)$ exist before I just described it?) I'll just repeat what I wrote: *Any line can be considered a [degenerate] hyperbola.* ... The term "degenerate" applies to objects that live on the fringe of their definitions; typically, they have lapsed into a form that lacks the qualities we usually think of. For instance, circles of zero (or *infinite*) radius aren't "round". [continued]

Comment: [continuing] Often, degenerate objects are *ambiguous*. A "flat" triangle with collinear vertices is visually indistinguishable from a segment; you can't tell from looking what the third vertex is. Now, I may have gotten to that triangle by gradually moving the apex of an isosceles triangle toward its base; within that family, the "flat" member's "apex" is the midpoint; some other approach could have the third point coincide with a trisecting-point, or one of the vertices. Without knowledge of the process, *you can't tell*. [continued]

Comment: [continuing] Likewise, with your conjugate-axis hyperbola. (Note that "conjugate hyperbola" already has meaning, so don't get them confused. :) For a given hyperbola, there's an entire family —called a "pencil"— of hyperbolas sharing that hyperbola's foci; in particular, the conjugate-axis hyperbola is the member of the family with *infinite* eccentricity. But, if you saw that figure without the context of that original hyperbola, it's *visually indistinguishable* from a line, so you *can't tell by looking* where its foci are; *any* point in the plane *could* be one of them. [I'll stop here.]