# True or False: A line is a parabola.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

It is known that a line is a degenerate parabola. But if asked as above, what is the better answer?

Context: This question appeared on a quiz recently given in our Precalculus class. It is not clear to me and my classmates if the answer is True or False. Our book says the following. 
[image]

Comment: Almost always. .

Comment: Why not always?

Comment: Where did you get that definition? A parabola is the set of points equidistant from a point (focus) and a line (directrix). What are the focus and directrix of a line?

Comment: All parabola are similar to one another.  And lines are not similar to parabola.  A degenerate parabola is not a parabola.

Comment: @JohnDouma You could take any point on the line as "focus" and the perpendicular through that point as "directrix". But unlike a proper parabola, the "degenerate parabola" has more than one choice of "focus" and "directrix". It also fails to have other properties that all proper parabolas have.

Comment: @JohnDouma, that is exactly what I was thinking. My answer is false because the focus-directrix definition of a parabola will not work for a line. The first sentence in the question above is not really a definition, but is simply a special case.

Comment: @DavidK, can you cite a property of all nondegenerate parabolas that lines do not satisfy?

Comment: I tend to favor "inclusive" definitions, so I'd say: *True, degenerate parabolas are parabolas.* That said, it's perfectly reasonable to have an "exclusive" view; indeed, I suspect that *most* discussions *implicitly assume* it. (When discussing parabolas/circles/triangles/whatever here, I almost-never even think to qualify my remarks as applying only to "non-degenerate" instances. It can be instructive to see what happens when figures degenerate, though.) In any case, anyone who ends such a conversation at "true or false" is doing an intellectual disservice to the topic and the conversers.

Comment: Related: [Is the conjugate axis of a hyperbola itself a trivial hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292478/409). I have some additional comments there about degeneracy.

Comment: Don't let language define reality.  Let reality define language.

Comment: @HenryRazon: The textbook *explicitly states* that degenerate cases are included in the classification of second-degree $xy$ polynomials. If the textbook *defines* a conic as the graph of such a polynomial, then the degenerate cases count. Now, if the textbook *defined* conics by other means, then degeneracies may-or-may-not be included for whatever reason. Even then, your instructor may have opted to promote an alternative view, and the quiz may reflect that view. (When I teach, I very often think outside-the-book.) This is really a discussion/debate you should be having with your instructor.

Answer (score 2):

No, in almost all contexts. Very occasionally you might encounter a family of parabolas one of which is degenerate; then it might be acceptable.

If you have been asked this question, tell us the context.

Answer (score 1):

The parabola is $y^2=4ax$, if you put $a=0$, it becomes a line $y=0$. So one may say that a line is a parabola whose length of latus-rectum is zero. This is how a parabola degenerates to a line. A line is the thinnest parabola.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the parabola $~y=a~x^2~$.

All parabolas can be rotated and translated to arrive at this form. Hence this equation covers all possible parabolas in the $2$D plane for the purpose of this problem.

Now, for a straight line to exist, we should be able to find a point where $~\frac{dy}{dx}~$ does not change.

But, $~\frac{dy}{dx}=2ax~$

The derivative is different for all points on the parabola since it is dependent on $~x~$ and there is only one $~y~$ for each $~x~$.

So we can conclude that the statement is **false**.

**************-

see https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-there-are-no-straight-lines-in-a-parabola

Comment: But what if $a=0$?